# Error on runtime "Could not load file or assembly 'Select.HtmlToPdf, Version=2.4.0.1" on SharePoint 2013. Using Select.HtmlToPdf 3rd Party Library

Tags: asp.net, pdf, sharepoint-2013, html-to-pdf

**My Error**:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Select.HtmlToPdf, Version=2.4.0.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e0ae9f6e27a97018' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Okay so far, I have created my webpart and installed Select.HtmlToPdf package through this command "PM> Install-Package Select.HtmlToPdf " (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/)

I get no error at deployment, Only at run time. Though everything looks fine and at place to me but this error just won't go. Am I doing something wrong or missing anything here?

**Edit**: This error comes only when I try to run Select.HtmlToPdf on SharePoint 2013 (Visual WebPart)

**My Code:**

```
using SelectPdf;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace downloadPDF.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetRecord();
            }
        }
        private bool startConversion = false;
        private void GetRecord()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startConversion = true;
        }
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (startConversion)
            {
                // get html of the page
                TextWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myWriter);
                base.Render(htmlWriter);

                // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
                HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

                // create a new pdf document converting the html string of the page
                PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(
                    myWriter.ToString(), Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

                // save pdf document
                doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

                // close pdf document
                doc.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // render web page in browser
                base.Render(writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Tom said, I added Select.PdfToHtml.dll library to GAC.

"I tried to add the Select.HtmlToPdf.dll file in GAC and it worked like a charm. I double clicked on Package.package > Advanced > Add > Add from existing assemblies > Selected my Select.HtmlToPdf.dll(Net20) > Check Deployment target as GAC > Save!
References: [add library to GAC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b9ef307-e15c-4bc1-b5c0-dfc7aef04900/deploying-third-party-dll-from-solution?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) [Could not load file or assembly Select.HtmlToPdf](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d/view/Discussions) "

After that, I could load my page and see my content. but when I clicked button; I got this error

> *"Conversion failure. Could not find 'Select.Html.dep'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code."*

To fix this follow below steps:

> firstly I copied my Select.Html.Dep file(Net20) to my 15 hive folder
>   "\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SelectPDFTest\VisualWebPart1\Select.Html.Dep"
>
> then I set my full path like this in Code:
>
> "// create a new pdf document converting the html string of the page
>                   SelectPdf.GlobalProperties.HtmlEngineFullPath = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SelectPDFTest\VisualWebPart1\Select.Html.dep";
>                   PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(myWriter.ToString(),
>   Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);" Reference: [Could not load file or assembly Select.HtmlToPdf](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-from-HTML-to-PDF-09ce2a1d/view/Discussions)

So Finally, my code looks like this:

```
using SelectPdf;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace SelectPDFTest.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetRecord();
            }
        }
        private bool startConversion = false;
        private void GetRecord()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            startConversion = true;
        }
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (startConversion)
            {
                // get html of the page
                TextWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();

                HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myWriter);
                base.Render(htmlWriter);

                // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
                HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

                // set css @media screen
                converter.Options.CssMediaType = HtmlToPdfCssMediaType.Screen;

                // create a new pdf document converting the html string of the page
                SelectPdf.GlobalProperties.HtmlEngineFullPath = @"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Web Server Extensions\\15\\TEMPLATE\\CONTROLTEMPLATES\\SelectPDFTest\\VisualWebPart1\\Select.Html.dep";

                string css = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/Style Library/css/main.css' media='screen' />   ";
                string pageHtml = css + myWriter.ToString();

                PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(pageHtml, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

                // save pdf document
                doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

                // close pdf document
                doc.Close();

                startConversion = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // render web page in browser
                base.Render(writer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With any SharePoint WebPart that uses 3rd party libraries, the solution is to add that library to GAC:

Click on Package.package > Advanced > Add > Add from existing assemblies > Selected Select.HtmlToPdf.dll > Check Deployment target as GAC > Save!

More details here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b9ef307-e15c-4bc1-b5c0-dfc7aef04900/deploying-third-party-dll-from-solution?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Yes Thank you, it helped.