# Could not load file or assembly 'Select.Html.dep'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I have a project that uses Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore - everything is working great.

Today i have the requirement to add a WCF Web Service.

I tried this using the normal Manage Connected Services > Other Services > Configure WCF Web Service Reference, which has always worked for me before.

But, it steps through and then pukes with this message:

```
[13/07/2021 14:26:50.725] Adding Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider to the project.
[13/07/2021 14:26:50.726] Importing web service metadata ...
[13/07/2021 14:26:50.744] Number of service endpoints found: 1
[13/07/2021 14:26:50.764] Scaffolding service reference code ...
[13/07/2021 14:27:05.041] Error:Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Select.Html.dep'. The module cannot be loaded because only single file assemblies are supported. (0x8013101E)
[13/07/2021 14:27:05.791] Done.
[13/07/2021 14:27:05.859] Failed adding Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider to the project.
```

I do indeed have a file at the root of my solution. And it definitely seems to be a file that the HtmlToPdf package depends on.

Can anyone shed any light on how to fix this problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Note that it's especially helpful with regards to a fix, but this may shed more light on the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612638/error-the-module-cannot-be-loaded-because-only-single-file-assemblies-are-supp

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the select.htmltopdf nuget package, here is the page you can install this:[Select.HtmlToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/).

Comment: i already have it. as i said the code runs and compiles with no problems

Comment: I find a reference, the solution is to add that library to GAC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714233/error-on-runtime-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-select-htmltopdf-version-2-4